# Handling large transactions: any time/memory tradeoffs?

Tags: performance, transactions, neo4j, cypher

In our system there is a (quite common) case where user's action can trigger operation that involves setting/removing labels onto/from nodes *and* relationships amounting to a total order of hundreds of thousands entities. (Remove label `A` from 100K nodes, set label `B` to 80K labels, set property `[x,y,z]` to 20K nodes and so on). Of course, I can't squeeze them all in one transaction and, thanks to the fact that these nodes can easily be separated into a large number of subsets, I perform the actions inside some number of separate transactions, which, of course, breaks all the ACIDity, but satisfies us in terms of performance.  If I, however, try to nest those transaction into a single large one **to rule them all**, that top-level transaction tries to track all internal transactions' updates to DB, which, of course, results in an extremely poor performance.

What can you guys recommend me to solve the problem?

My config (well, its relevant parts):

```
"org.neo4j.server.database.mode" : "HA",
"use_memory_mapped_buffers" : "true",
"neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory" : "450M",
"neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory" : "450M",
"neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory" : "450M",
"neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory" : "300M",
"neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory" : "50M",
"cache_type" : "hpc",
"dense_node_threshold" : "15",
"query_cache_size" : "150"
```

Any hints and clues are much appreciated :)

Comment: How much heap do you provide? If you have reasonable heap sizes (e.g. 4 to 16GB you should be able to fit up to 1M operations into one huge tx).

Comment: You certainly don't need 450M nodestore, read the section on mmio cache configuration or just look at your store-files to find sensible values for the mmio config.

Comment: I read that section and did the math, and it's really a bit more than I need now, but there are other operations like selecting (possibly ~100K) nodes with the certain label and reading some property from them, and there might be > 1 simultaneous requests of such a nature, so I decided to put some (un)reasonably large figure there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that modifying hundreds of thousands of entities as a result of a user action in the same transaction isn't going to be performant. Nested transactions in Neo4j are just "placebo" transactions, as you correctly point out.

I would start by thinking about alternative strategies to achieve your goal (which I know nothing about) without needing to update so many entities.

If an alternative isn't possible, I would ask whether it is ok for the updates to happen a short time after the user action. If the answer is yes, then I would store a message about the user action in a persistent queue, which I would process asynchronously. That way, the user call returns quickly and the update happens eventually.

Finally, if it is acceptable for the time between the user action and the large update to take even longer, I would consider and "agent" that continuously crawls the graph and updates the labels of the entities that it encounters, as opposed to transaction-driven updates. Have a look at [GraphAware NodeRank](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-noderank) for inspiration.